# How to get id from form in .html template in django python

Tags: python, django

I'm building a student management system and I need to fetch subject id in order to call a redirect method that takes in that subject id to enroll it. I don't use form.py to create a form (if there's a way to do it that way, I'm open to learning it), but I fetch all subjects and have user choose which one they want to enroll.

Here is my code:

This method is used to get .html form but I don't know how to retrieve data (in this case subject id) from the form when you click on submit:

```
def enroll(request, id_user):
    subjects = Subjects.objects.all()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'enrollSubject.html', {'subjects': subjects})
    if request.method == "POST":
        ----How to fetch anything from the .html above (in this case subject id)---
        return redirect('../enroll/add/' + str(id_user) + '/' + str(id_subject))
```

This is my .html file:

```
<form method="POST">
        <select>
            {% for subject in subjects %}
            <option value="{{subject.id}}">{{subject.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
```

Is there a way to fetch the value in `<option value="{subject.id}">{subject.name}</option>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using [url reversion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) (second example) in `redirect` calls instead of concatenating hardcoded url parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute will be used to identify the selected value when the form is submitted like subject_id .And then the selected subject ID is retrieved using request.POST.get('subject_id').

```
  from django.shortcuts import redirect
        
        def enroll(request, id_user):
            subjects = Subjects.objects.all()
            if request.method == "GET":
                return render(request, 'enrollSubject.html', 
                {'subjects':subjects})
            elif request.method == "POST":
                subject_id = request.POST.get('subject_id')
                if subject_id:
                    return redirect(f'../enroll/add/{id_user}/{subject_id}')
                else:
                    # redirection logic here
                    return redirect('../enroll/')
```

Html file:

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="subject_id">
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <option value="{{ subject.id }}">{{ subject.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Enroll</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a name attribute in the select tag.
The `request.POST` dictionary should contain the value indexed to the key of the name attr in the option tag.

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="subject">
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <option value="{{subject.id}}">{{subject.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```